# How to use react-native-blurhash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to use react-native-blurhash? Can anyone tell me how can i use react-native-blurhash to make image blur according to that image background color it display blur colors if its loading the image by encode it can be done which is provided by the package but how can i do that? i am getting multiple feedimages https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-blurhash

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';

const Card = ({ username, feedImage }) => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const source = useMemo(() => ({ uri: feedImage }), [feedImage]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.c1}>
                {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator style={styles.spinner} />}
                <Text style={styles.username}>{username}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                <FastImage
                    source={source}
                    style={styles.image}
                    onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)}
                />
                {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator style={styles.spinner} />}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Card
```